# How to show a message when the client doesn't use Chrome?

Tags: html

You also see it on Google search homepage. If the client doesn't use Chrome, then you'll see a promotion message for Chrome. It doesn't show up when the client is already using Chrome.

I'd like to achieve the same on my website. If the client is not using Chrome, then I'd like to display a message.

> "For Better View Use Chrome"

How can I achieve this? I'm using HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: _"For Better View Use Chrome"_ Mmm, welcome to the old days _"Best viewed in Netscape"_. You can't detect browsers with plain html. You can only use IE conditional tags which will detect any version of IE but that's it. Use javascript for this.

Comment: @elclanrs Do you have IE conditional tags Code. Please Post that in as Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `window.chrome` in JavaScript.

```
<script>
    if (window.chrome) {
        alert('chrome');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how to find the other browsers.

Comment: Just inverse the condition. `if (!window.chrome) alert('Not chrome');`

Comment: Does this work for Chrome browser on mobile devices? I'm guessing it does, but just need to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Per request, here's conditional code for IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    Code for any IE in here. You can load css and/or js.
<![endif]-->
```

If you use jQuery you can do:

```
if (!$.browser.webkit) {} // Targets non-wekbit browsers, Chrome, Safari...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(!(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))){
    alert("This browser is not fully supported yet, For best results please use Chrome");
}
```